# Casting with pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

Say I have an object:

```
void *tmpValue;
```

and say I know that tmpValue points to a double.
A way to cast this into a double is to do the following:

```
double* dblPtr = (double*) tmpValue;
double dbl = *dblPtr;
```

But why does a direct casting from void* to double not work?

```
double dbl = (double) tmpValue; //error: "cannot convert from 'void*' to 'double'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want `*(double*)tmpValue`

Comment: What do you mean by "work"? `tmpValue` is a pointer, so what you're asking makes no sense.

Comment: Because this one: "double* dblPtr = (double*) tmpValue;" is the same as "double* dblPtr = (double) (*tmpValue);" <-- This way you cast the value...

Comment: the casting is always from pointer to pointer, so, at least, you have to cast like    
    *(double*)tmpValue

Comment: You can't dereference a generic pointer, so `(*tmpValue)` would fail to compile.

Comment: Why do you think it should work? It doesn't make sense to cast a pointer to a double directly.

Comment: now that people pointed it out, it's clear to me why this wouldn't work. I'm new to c++ so thank you all for the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interpreting a pointer (a memory address) as a floating-point value is not a sensible operation, and it probably fails on your platform because `void *` and `double` are not even the same size.

What you want to do is interpret the pointer as `double *` and dereference that `double *` pointer, as in your second code snippet.

You can do this in one line:

```
double dbl = *(double *)tmpValue;
```

But, hey, this is C++. Better to do

```
double dbl = *static_cast<double *>(tmpValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast from a pointer type to double. Recall that pointer type is essentially a memory address (typically 4 bytes containing location information of the data on the memory). Hence you can cast pointer type to integer, but casting to double wouldn't make sense.

When you cast the void* pointer into double* pointer type, you are essentially saying "this is now an address of a double rather than an address of void*"

If you want to get the value as double in one liner nevertheless, you can do

```
double dbl = *( (double*) tmpValue );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
double dbl = *(double*)tmpValue
```

Answer (score -2):

dereference the pointer and cast ist value

Comment: eLRull gave the correct awnser. You are trying to convert a pointer to a value which is trying to interpret a memory address as a double.